# Watched tags: design flaw

Tags: bug, design

The title in one of the sidebar boxes isn't right. I hadn't noticed this before, so it may be new, although I don't think we've had any tweaks recently. Or perhaps it's just me and my browser (Chrome 67.0.3396.99 (64-bit) on Windows), or it may be a moderator thing if the *Edit* link is restricted.

The words "Favorite tags" should be centred, with the decorative thingies right on the edge of the box, like the one below it. I'm not sure where "edit" should appear. Perhaps something like
"Edit | Add a favorite tag"

[image: Favorite tags sidebar]

That box has now been superseded by a different one:

[image: New "Watched tags" box]

But the CSS spacing appears to have been applied to the bottom of the "Watched tags" box rather than the top. So it's still a bug, just a different one. And I really dislike the crude image of binoculars which doesn't match anything else in the theme.

At least "Watched tags" means that the spelling of "Favourite" is no longer an issue!

Comment: The binoculars are a bit jarring... an image of a magnifying glass might be preferable. But "watch a tag", I suppose, is inspired by birdwatching.

Comment: Wait, those are binoculars? Here I was sure they were two Trappist monks clinking their celebratory mugs of Lenten ale together!

Comment: I thought they were robots trying to figure out how to shake hands, or possibly two space stations docking. What with all the stars.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching